# Exporting After Effect file with Bodymovin for Lottie (iOS)

Tags: ios, after-effects, lottie

I would like to load a 3d diamond realised with this After Effects [tutorial](http://easyaftereffects.net/sims-diamond-in-after-effects/) in my iOS app using the Lottie-iOS library. 
Unfortunately, when I export it with Bodimovin in .json format (to be loaded in my iOS app) both lighting and animation seems inactive. Also, the background appears as a flat fill whereas I would like to display a nice shading effect. 
Desired results:

[image]

But I get this:

[image]

In the Bodymovin export options I select "Demo in the options" and export both elements.

[image]

I just would like to obtain the 3D model with the shading and possibly the backlighting.

Comment: Maybe you're using some unsupported feature of after effects by lottie. Check here https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios#currently-unsupported-after-effects-features

Comment: What would be the best solution to have an animated isometric-3d model displayed on a UIView?